# How to create a white image in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Upon doing my homework, I stumbled across a problem concerning Python and image manipulation. I must say, using the Image lib is not an option. So here it is

```
from scipy.misc import imread,imsave
from numpy import zeros

imga = zeros([100,100,3])
h = len(imga)
w = len(imga[0])

for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        imga[y,x] = [255,255,255]

imsave("Result.jpg",imga)
```

I would assume it makes my picture white, but it turns it black, and I have no idea why
It's not about the code (and I know it looks very ugly). Its just about the fact, that it is a black image.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Every color in an image is represented by one byte. So to create an image array, you should set it's dtype to uint8.

And, you don't need for-loop to set every elements to 255, you can use fill() method or slice index:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
img.fill(255) # or img[:] = 255
```

Comment: Ok since you mentioned that.
How do I use slicing combined with conditions.
For example if the y<50 and x<50 I want to set it to 255 otherwise to 0.

Comment: hey, could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778351/how-to-fill-the-values-in-numpy-to-create-a-specturm/69778828#69778828

Comment: Specify the `dtype=np.uint8` is important

Answer (score 10):

Easy!
Check the below Code:

```
whiteFrame = 255 * np.ones((1000,1000,3), np.uint8)
```

`255` is the color for filling the bytes.

`1000`, `1000` is the size of the image.

`3` is the color channel for the image.

And `unit8` is the type

Goodluck

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to create a white image with a python one liner.

```py
$ python3 -c "from PIL import Image;Image.new('RGB', (1900, 1080), color = (255,255,255)).save('Img.jpg')"
```

This will create a white image with a width of 1900 and hight of 1080.

Answer (score 2):

When creating imga, you need to set the unit type. Specifically, change the following line of code:

```
imga = zeros([100,100,3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

And, add the following to your imports:

```
import numpy as np
```

That gives a white image on my machine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like charm

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work]

Comment: You are creating an array of zeros..Shouldnt this give you a black image?

Comment: This actually gives a black image

Comment: black image for me

Comment: It will create a black image.

Comment: for everyone who is getting a black image, use this instead ---- 

255*np.ones([100,100,3], dtype=np.uint8)

Answer (score 2):

The headline is too broad and shows up at Google first.  I needed a white image and used PIL and numpy.  PILlow actually works well with numpy

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
img.fill(255) # numpy array!
im = Image.fromarray(img) #convert numpy array to image
im.save('whh.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just regarding the headline of this question, I did need a white image as well as a pillow input. And the solutions presented here did not work for me.

Therefore here a different way to generate white images for other purposes:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 50), color = (255,255,255))
```

Size and color may be changed in the 2nd and 3rd parameter of the Image.new()-function.

And if you want to write something on this image or save it, this would be example code for this.

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 30)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).text((0,0), "hello world", font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0))
img.save('test.jpg')
```

Answer (score -3):

```
# Create an array with a required colours
# The colours are given in BGR [B, G, R]
# The array is created with values of ones, the size is (H, W, Channels)
# The format of the array is uint8
# This array needs to be converted to an image of type uint8

selectedColor = [75, 19, 77] * np.ones((640, 480, 3), np.uint8)
imgSelectedColor = np.uint8(np.absolute(selectedColor))
```